# shell_exec not working with crontab

Tags: php, bash, cron

I'm trying to execute this command in php:

```
<?php
    shell_exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n* * * * * mycommand" | crontab -');
```

When I do this, nothing happens, no erros, no messages, nothing happens. But when I type it directly at the bash, It works nice!

So I made some google and some guys told to use `2>&1` at the end of the command. So:

```
<?php
    shell_exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n* * * * * mycommand" | crontab - 2>&1');
```

But now I'm having this error when I echo the output:

> "-":0: bad minute errors in crontab file, can't install.

What could be going on?

Comment: you get no errors because shell_exec doesn't output any. It returns any output from the command, but does NOT output that output itself. If you want to capture return values/errors, then you need to use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead.

Comment: exec does not have output. shell_exec has, right? And I'm getting output with shell_exec at the second test.

Comment: `shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string` nowhere does it say "output to screen".

Comment: I'm echo ing the string. I'll say it at the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try passthrough in php, that should give you errors on screen.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php